# DrawLine or DrawBitmap does not work in TextView's onDraw

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying perform a subclass on a textView. It won't work. When i extends the class from textView to View. It works. But i need the functionality of TextView.

But I am not able to perform any drawLine or drawBitmap on the onDraw() routine. But drawText() and drawColor() works. I don't understand why.

I cant find any problem with the onDraw(). Can someone tell me what did i do wrong on this? Or TextView does not allow drawing bitmap or lines?
below is my code

```
package com.name.name;

import android.content.Context;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RDisplay extends TextView {
    Paint p;
    private String mName = "";
    private static Bitmap mImage = null;
    Context mContext;

    public RDisplay (Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        initComponent();

    }

    public RDisplay (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        initComponent();
    }

    public void initComponent()
    {
        p = new Paint();
        p.setTextSize(30);
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        mName = name;

        String file = "f_" + name.toLowerCase();
            Drawable d = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
        mImage = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
        invalidate();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        // drawText() Working
        canvas.drawText(mName, 0, getMeasuredHeight(), paint); 
        // drawLine() Not Working
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), paint); 

        if(mImage != null)
        {   canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK); //Working
            canvas.drawBitmap(mImage, 10, 10, null); // Not working
        }
    }

    void setFont(String fontName)
    {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), fontName); 
        setTypeface(font); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never actually call `setName(String)` which leaves `mImage` as null. Also, I is good practice to **not** create paints in on draw. Create them in an initializer method and set them as you need.

Comment: the setName is used as a function call outside this class. 

I do not actually create paint initially. It is just that I could not display the bitmap, so i try creating a paint to see if i could draw out a line at least. But it couldn't.